# use dynamically loaded javascript as soon it gets loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the snippet of code that I am using to dynamically load a .`js` file in my `react` application.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > -1) {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = '../public/web/utils/flexibility.js';
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        script.onload = () => {
            // Here I want to use one of the function defined in my loaded `flexibility.js` 
            // file lets say this one flexibility(document.documentElement);

            };
        }
    }
```

Any insights on the same will be helpful.

Comment: What you are looking for is JSONP.

Comment: @Raymond I don't think so, there should be some way to do it in above snippet of code as well.